# PHP Mail $to multiple recipients from database table

Tags: php, email-address

```
<?php include("admin/db.php"); 
$recipients = "SELECT * FROM recipients ORDER BY id DESC";
$email_list = $db->query($recipients);
foreach($email_list as $row) {
    echo $row['email'].","; 
}

$to = "?";

?>
```

Above I have a comma delimitated list of emails which I need to insert into the $to variable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$recipients = "SELECT * FROM recipients ORDER BY id DESC";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($recipients))
{
    $adresses[] = $row['email']; 
}

$to = implode(",",$adresses);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($email_list as $row) {
    echo $row['email'].","; 


  mail($row['mail'], $subject, $body)

}
```